What is an explicit bijection between $[1,\infty)$ and $(1,\infty)$?
I am studying a very basic math course, so the simplest solution would be appreciated. I can't come up with how to map that 1 in the first set to an element of $(1,\infty)$

There are many duplicates, often mapping $[0,1]$ to $[0,1)$ or $(0,1]$

You can construct one by using Hilbert's infinite hotel idea.
Consider $f(x) = \begin{cases} x & x\not\in\mathbb{N} \\ x+1 & x\in \mathbb{N} \end{cases}$
This $f(x)$ shifts all natural number $( 1, 2, 3 \cdots)$ into its next number $(2, 3, 4\cdots)$. and does not affect the others.
Indeed, $f$ is a bijection between $[1,\infty]$ to $(1,\infty)$. You may fill in the details.

Oh, I was thinking of how to shift them itself, but could not come up with any function. Thanks so muc for the help!

Another idea. Take each interval of the form $[n,n+1)$ and reverse it. For example $[1,2)\to(1,2]$ with $x\mapsto3-x$.
This can be achieved with an explicit formula: $f(x)=2\lfloor x\rfloor-x+1$.
